# How to Make a Box and Whisker Plot in Excel with EPPLus?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I have a C#/ASP.NET program that exports and excel file using EPPlus. I would like to incorporate a box-and-whisker plot into my excel file. However, it doesn't seem to be a default chart type in EPPlus when I look at the options under eChartType, does anyone know how to get one of these charts into the exported excel file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more research it looks like the answer is no. Box Plots weren't added into Excel until the 2016 update and EPPlus is based on earlier versions. However, [this pdf from the NI](https://dpcpsi.nih.gov/sites/default/files/Box%20and%20whisker%20chart%20-%2006202017.pdf) describes how to approximate a box and whisker plot using a stacked bar chart and I suspect it would be possible to recreate this process using EPPlus.